# g++ handling of copying a std::complex

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly

As part of a self-education project I looked into how g++ handles `std::complex` - type and was puzzled by this simple function:

```
#include <complex>  
std::complex<double> c;

void get(std::complex<double> &res){
    res=c;
}
```

Compiled with `g++-6.3 -O3` (or also `-Os`) for Linux64 I got this result:

```
    movsd   c(%rip), %xmm0
    movsd   %xmm0, (%rdi)
    movsd   c+8(%rip), %xmm0
    movsd   %xmm0, 8(%rdi)
    ret
```

So it moves the real and imaginary parts individually as 64bit floats. However, I would expect the assembly to use two `movups` instead of four `movsd`, i.e. moving the real and imaginary parts simultaneously as a 128bit package:

```
    movups  c(%rip), %xmm0
    movups  %xmm0, (%rdi)
    ret
```

This is not only twice as fast on my machine (Intel Broadwell) as the `movsd`-version, but also needs only 16 bytes while the `movsd`-version needs 36 bytes.

What is the reason for the g++ creating an assembly with `movsd`?

1. There is an additional compiler flag to trigger the usage of `movups` which I should use next to `-O3`?
2. There are disadvantages of using `movups` I'm not aware of?
3. g++ does not produce optimal assembly here?
4. something else?

---

More context: I try to compare two possible function signatures:

```
std::complex<double> get(){
    return c;
}
```

and

```
void get(std::complex<double> &res){
    res=c;
}
```

The first version has to put the real part and the imaginary part into different registers (`xmm0` and `xmm1`) because of the SystemV ABI. But with the second version one could try to take some advantages of the SSE-operations which works on 128bits, however it does not work with my g++-version.

---

Edit: As kennytm's answer suggest, the g++ seems to produce non-optimal assembly. It always uses 4 movsd for copying an std::complex from one memory location to another, as for example in

```
void get(std::complex<double> *res){
    res[1]=res[0];
}
```

There is now a [bug-report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=80372) filed to gcc-bugzilla..

Comment: I've got `movsd   c+8(%rip), %xmm1; movsd   c(%rip), %xmm0` using https://gcc.godbolt.org/

Comment: Interestingly, `godbolt.org`'s [output](https://godbolt.org/g/vRKFE0) is a little different form yours. That might also be your explanation: Since both values are returned in separate registers, it makes no sense to use `movups`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 3. g++ does not produce optimal assembly here.

Both `clang` and  `icc` use only one SSE register. You can check the compiled code in https://godbolt.org/g/55lPv0.

```
get(std::complex<double>&):
        movups    c(%rip), %xmm0
        movups    %xmm0, (%rdi)  
        ret
```